# Is there a way to clear an old application cache (Nextjs app)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

So I have a problem that some of my users keep seeing an old verion of my app that was made with react, recently we changed it and now we are using nextjs but some users did not recieve the update and cached old version keep poping up for them.

I wanted to know if its possible to automatically remove that old cached files for them?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume you site is static. If so, your problem is likely with how browsers operate to speed up the web. Your old version likely has a long-lived [cache policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) on `.html` files.

When deploying static sites like React or Next SSG, you must not cache any `.html` for an extended period.  If the cache-policy has a long-lived [max-age](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control#expiration) you will run into this issue on every update.

Even though Next.js versions the assets, they are included in `.html` files.  If you cache the `.html` files, the browser will not know that the assets have changed.

If you use a CDN service like [AWS Cloud Front](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) you can likely [invalidate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html) the cache in the service and push a new static version with a short lived or `no-cahce` policy on `.html` files.

Even after updating your http `cache-control` headers, your current users will likely still need to manually invalidate their browser cache or wait for it to expire.